# Archlinux, startxfce4 working properly in root, but not working properly in other user

Tags: root, archlinux, xorg, xfce

I've installed arch linux x64 on my computer. I added other user. Also I added this new user to common groups. When I type `startxfce4` by *root*, xfce4 runs properly and it's possible to use it. But when I type `startxfce4` by *newly added user* xfce4 also runs. But instead default mouse in background I can see black screen, can't see cursor. Panels are visible. After call "turn off" dialog (I can't see cursor, but panels are working and I can see if cursor is on a button of the panel) cursor appearances. If the cursor hovers panels it's ok. But if this cursor is over background I can see big cross cursor like in checking of working xorg-server. When I run `su` before executing `startxfce4` xfce4 also doesn't work correctly. What did I forget during install xorg-server, xfce4 or during adding new user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=210182). In a nutshell the problem was xfwm4 wasn't running,  I forgot do [that](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xfce#Default_window_manager). I typed `xfconf-query -c xfce4-session -p /sessions/Failsafe/Client0_Command -t string -sa xfwm4` and it worked.

Comment: In other words, don't run `Xorg` as `root`.